# Changing .fl file in fluid doesn't change the UI when run with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, fluid

I am working on a C++ project on Visual Studio which relies on UserInterface.fl file for its GUI. Intuitively I would understand that changing the UserInterface.fl file with FLTK would allow me to see those changes on actual GUI when built and run with Visual Studio, however that doesn't happen.

I have already tried restarting Visual Studio and rescanning and rebuilding the project but it hasn't helped.

The .fl contains the following lines of code to which I have tried to make changes as well to see results, but without success.

```
    header_name {UserInterface.h}
    code_name {UserInterface.cpp}
```

I would expect the changes to be visible on the GUI as soon as I change the UserInterface.fl file using FLTK without even having to alter the UserInterface.cpp or UserInterface.h files.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLTK's fluid environment is completely different from your Visual Studio .sln solution. Thus your files would not automatically update to show the changes made through Fluid. However, you should be able to find the option of "Write Code" under the "File" menu in fluid. The shortcut is "Ctrl+Shift+c". This writes your code to the corresponding .h and .cpp file.